# Bootstrap - Define Css for 4 Column table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 4 column table and the CSS is as below. It defines the sizes of the columns in css within using the first `child + td` syntax. For example the 3rd column is:

```
.tbl4Cols td:first-child + td + td
```

In Bootstrap md and above sized screen it should show all 4 columns on single line and in sm screen it should show 2 columns on each row. So the inline CSS and HTML would be as in HTML snippet below. However my HTML is dynamic and I want to just mark the outer `div` or `table` with `class="bootStrapRow4Cols"` and have CSS applied to all **cols** dynamically so I need to replicate the 1st child col, 2nd child col etc. syntax using CSS and Bootstrap. Any ideas?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS for the 4 olumn table is as below:

```
/* tbl4Cols: Used to display entities in 4 columns:
  Label1: | Control1 | Label2 | Control2
*/
.tbl4Cols {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-top: 0.75em;
  border: 0 none;
}

  .tbl4Cols tr {
    border: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
  }

  .tbl4Cols td {
    border: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 2px 1em 2px 1em;
  }

    /*lable1 column*/
    .tbl4Cols td:first-child {
      text-align: right;
      width: 20%;
      max-width: 20%;
      min-width: 20%;
    }

      /*control1 column*/
      .tbl4Cols td:first-child + td {
        width: 30%;
        max-width: 30%;
        min-width: 30%;
      }

        /*lable2 column*/
        .tbl4Cols td:first-child + td + td {
          text-align: right;
          width: 20%;
          max-width: 20%;
          min-width: 20%;
        }

          /*control2 column*/
          .tbl4Cols td:first-child + td + td + td {
            width: 30%;
            max-width: 30%;
            min-width: 30%;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example markup, it seems more practical to just use `tr:nth-child(odd) { ... }` and `tr:nth-child(even) { ... }`.

As for stacking at smaller screen resolutions, below is what you'll find in Bootstrap.css.

```
table col[class*="col-"] {
  position: static;
  display: table-column;
  float: none;
}
table td[class*="col-"],
table th[class*="col-"] {
  position: static;
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
```

You can use @media queries to use `float: left;` to stack the cells at col-sm-* instead of `float: none;`. Just make sure you reference your custom style sheet after bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css.

Hope this gets you started in the right direction.